# R curl upload breakes down for large files because of showing progress

Tags: r, curl, large-files

I am using curl::curl_upload to upload large csv files to a ftp server. The function breaks down with the following error message:

```
Uploaded 2147418112 bytes...Error in sprintf("\rUploaded %d bytes...", total_bytes) : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

I assume the reason is that the sprintf function uses integers? 2147418112 seems suspiciously close to 2^31-1. Actually, 2^31-2147418112 is exactly 2^16. Because it updates the progress in steps of 2^16?

I can avoid this problem with verbose = F.

Is there a way to still get progress? (How) can I overwrite the progress function? I would use View(curl_upload) and copy the code, replace the progress with the following and use my own curl_upload2.
Is there an alternative/better way to do this?

```
cat(sprintf("\rUploaded %d bytes...", total_bytes) # curl
cat(sprintf("\rUploaded %.0f bytes ...", total_bytes) # modified
```

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug report here: https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues?

Comment: Which version of curl are you using? For me the line reads like `cat(sprintf("\rUploaded %.0f bytes...", total_bytes), file = stderr())` so basically already what you need (`curl_5.0.0`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The current version already fixed this. The server I was working on had 4.3.1 :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be fixed with a decent version of `curl`, but as the question was how to overwrite the progress function without doing a copy & paste here's a solution using `trace`:

1. First you need to find out where the `cat` sits in `curl_upload`. You can use `as.list(body(curl_upload))` to get the proper indices. You may need to dive deeper into the nested structure in case the `cat` sits in a nested structure (like here), but some try and error should reveal that:

   ```r
   as.list(body(curl_upload))[[6]][[3]][[4]]           ## the inner function
   as.list(body(curl_upload))[[6]][[3]][[4]][[3]][[4]] ## line before the verbose `if`
   ```

   gives you the correct positions.
2. Now you can inject code which:

   1. Sets `verbose` locally to `FALSE` avoiding the original verbose line.
   2. Adds your own updated `cat` statement (I simply added the string `[UPDATE]` to show that indeed my `cat` statement is called and not the original one:

   ```r
   library(curl)
   untrace(curl_upload)
   trace(curl_upload, quote({
            verbose <- FALSE
            if (length(buf) == 0 || identical(total_bytes, infilesize)) {
                cat(sprintf("\r[UPDATE:] Uploaded %.0f bytes... all done!\n", 
                    total_bytes), file = stderr())
            } else {
                cat(sprintf("\r[UPDATE:] Uploaded %.0f bytes...", total_bytes), 
                    file = stderr())
            }
         }), at = list(c(6, 3, 4, 3, 4)), print = FALSE)
   ```

Et voilà.

If you now try out `curl_upload` you will see that

1. The original `verbose` messages are skipped.
2. Your own messages are printed.

```r
fn <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
cat("New Line\n\n", file = fn)
res <- curl_upload(fn, "https://httpbin.org/put")
# [UPDATE:] Uploaded 12 bytes... all done!
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about trace. I assume this only works for functions where I can "see" the code?
purrr::map for example only lets me "see" _map and not how the progress is displayed/calculated.

Comment: Well, you see that `purrr::map` uses `purrr:::map_` which you can also inspect. BUT: some function do the printing in `C` and not in `R`. In these cases your options are limited, if you do not want to re-compile the source code for the original `C` libs.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed shortly after posting that map_ is internal. Bad example. But yes, I meant functions with printing in C or something like as_mapper = function (.f, ...) 
{
  UseMethod("as_mapper")
}

Comment: The last example would usually resolve to `as_mapper.default` and class specific implementations, e.g. `as.data.frame` has implementation in `as.data.frame.default` or `as.data.frame.matrix`.